# link to angular package and develop in local machine

Tags: angular

I'm developing angular 4 applications. Our apps structure is like below:

`ng-company -->` utility and assets package.

`ng-app -->`  angular app that **uses** ng-company package as dependency

The **question** is "how to see changes result in ng-company packages **without** publishing it to our Nexus OSS and then reinstall it in our `ng-app`?

**Environment**:

My OS is windows.

edited:

I googled and found 2 solutions:

1) Using npm link or yarn link

2) pack ng-company and then `yarn add path/to/ng-company.tgz`

I think **link** is solution but link it is not working. Webpack raise errors with title bellow

`Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated`

Answer (score -1):

it's not possible to use your developing library without publishing on nexus but there are some dirty ways:

1 - first you can copy and paste your build library every time you update it in your node_modules

2 - next you can import your build library and it's external path as and external js file in your main index.html file of ng-app

Comment: I have edited my question. I think  this is not solution. https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/

Comment: @HadiRasouli yes i thought with every local build it builds in server too. but with the ways you tried whats happening? is there any error or ?

Comment: when i choose symlink solution, in second package i face this error "  Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated" with webpack. Have you faced this error?

Comment: @HadiRasouli no i didn't but i suggest to delete your ```/target``` directory and ```yarn.lock``` file.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, it will be great if you share a github link or a website address, thanks.